# Remove features and dynamic vector layer from the map

Tags: openlayers

Fixed the problem of showing or hiding the vector layer on the map after executing a query, I find that after a new search, the previous vector layer is not removed, it remains on the map.
I tried to make a vectorlayer.clear (), before adding the new features to the new vector layer, but when checking to show or hide the vector layer, at least the one generated when doing the previous search is always visible.

```
function drawAbundance(cbx_espId){
    var vectorAbundance = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new  ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
            var proj = projection.getCode();
            var url = "Abundance.php"
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var params = {
                abundance: cbx_espId,
            }
            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            var onError = function() {
               vectorAbundance.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
            }
            xhr.onerror = onError;
            xhr.onload = function() {
                xhr.responseText;
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    **//I tried to put here:**
                    **//vectorAbundance.clear();**
                    vectorAbundance.addFeatures(
                        vectorAbundance.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText)
                    );
                    //map.getView().fit(vectorAbundance.getExtent());
                    $("#formEsp")[0].reset();
               } else {
                 onError();
               }
             }
             xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        },
    });
    vectorlayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source:vectorAbundance,
        visible:true,
        displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
        style: style,
        maxZoom:9,          
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorlayer)
}
//check to show or hidde the vector layer
function add_layer(evt){
    if(evt.checked){
        map.removeLayer(vectorlayer);
        //map.addLayer(vectorlayer);
    }else{
        //map.removeLayer(vectorlayer);
        map.addLayer(vectorlayer);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make the previous search not keep on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new layer with each call to `drawAbundance`, so it is not the old layer you are removing or clearing.  It would be better to maintain a single layer and replace its source

```
vectorlayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    visible:true,
    displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
    style: style,
    maxZoom:9,
});
map.addLayer(vectorlayer);

function drawAbundance(cbx_espId){
    var vectorAbundance = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new  ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
            var proj = projection.getCode();
            var url = "Abundance.php"
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var params = {
                abundance: cbx_espId,
            }
            xhr.open('POST', url);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            var onError = function() {
               vectorAbundance.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
            }
            xhr.onerror = onError;
            xhr.onload = function() {
                xhr.responseText;
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    vectorAbundance.addFeatures(
                        vectorAbundance.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText)
                    );
                    //map.getView().fit(vectorAbundance.getExtent());
                    $("#formEsp")[0].reset();
               } else {
                 onError();
               }
             }
             xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
        },
    });
    vectorLayer.setSource(vectorAbundance);
}
```

It might also be better to use `.setVisible(true)` and `.setVisible(false)` to show or hide instead of adding and removing the layer.

Comment: I tried your solution @Mike and it gave me an error adding the vectorlayer immediately after declaring it: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addLayer' of undefined". What I did was declare it in the array of layers that I later declare in the map variable, and it seems to work without a problem.
Thank you very much for your help